# Can not drag and drop UITableViewController into Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

A book I am using is telling me to drag and drop `UITableViewController` in object library into `Main.storyboard`, but it's not working. The `UITableViewController` just rushes back to object library. What's the problem? It works fine with "Table View". I am using Xcode 7.2, and OS X El Capitan.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't drag a Table View Controller to IB, then don't do it. Use a Table View instead! They are (mostly) the same.

I guess your book is telling you how to create a simple table view. So let *me* tell you how to create a simple table view in a view controller.

Of course, you should first drag a view controller to IB. Then add a table view to the view controller. Add the constraints if you want. Then run the app!

You will probably see a few horizontal lines on the screen and you can scroll it. How nice!

Now how do you add contents to the table? Just create a view controller class file and associate it with the view controller you just created. Then make that class conforms to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol and add the required methods. Finally, just associate the class with the table view's data source property. I think your book will talk about this in detail.

If you want to know more, visit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s78ndDj8K3U&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGDgp7nGSUnnXihbTLFZJ79B&index=21

Comment: Thank you so much!! It has been so helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't drop a view controller on top of another view controller.

(This is why you are able to drop a Table View onto a view controller, but not drop a Table View Controller.)

Instead, drag the Table View Controller to a blank area of the storyboard.  It will be droppable, and appear on the storyboard.

Note that Interface Builder changes the appearance of the droppable object to include a + sign when it's over an area where it can be dropped (and added to the storyboard).